# Compare a rows in a table for simularites and diffrences

Tags: mysql

I have an issue that I need to block bots on a site and need a list of there account to block

Question to answer is this.
Same account using a different IP address at the same time.
I need a simple table of account numbers I can quickly copy and paste into my security

If account number appears 2 or more times under a different IP address at the same time then show me the account number.

Here is an example of the table I am working with.

```
Table temp1
 account          ip            last_used   
14K4cHc     79.110.19.199   2016-01-07 09:06:52
17FFhQY     79.110.19.199   2016-01-07 09:06:52
14K4cHc     91.215.136.75   2016-01-07 09:06:52
17FFhQY     91.215.136.75   2016-01-07 09:06:52
15LESsr     193.9.158.98    2016-01-07 09:06:51
```

Lines 1 thru 4 are an example of the same 2 accounts using 2 different IP addresses at the same time spamming the site and is a possible bot.

Comment: I have figured out how to look for duplacate accounts with.        SELECT account, COUNT( account ) AS NumOccurrences
FROM temp1
GROUP BY account
HAVING (
COUNT( account ) >1
)

Comment: I have figured out how to look for duplacate accounts with.        SELECT account, COUNT( account ) AS NumOccurrences
FROM temp1
GROUP BY account
HAVING (
COUNT( account ) >1
)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  How do I also compare the last_used column at the same time so that I am not just seeing an account that has a different IP address at a different time?

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, to identify different IP addresses for the same account and last_used time, we could use a query something like this:

```
  SELECT t.account
       , t.last_used
       , COUNT(DISTINCT t.ip) AS cnt_ip
    FROM temp1 t
   GROUP BY t.account, t.last_used
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.ip) > 1
  ORDER BY t.account, t.last_used
```

This is probably more rows that you actually want to return, since it also returns distinct values of `last_used`.

The `GROUP BY` collapses all rows that have the same values for the specified expressions. In this case, the `account` and `last_used`.

The `COUNT(DISTINCT )` gets the number of unique IP addresses for each collapsed group. If all of the IP addresses for given `account` and `last_used` values are  non-NULL and equal, this will return a value of 1. We include a `HAVING` clause to filter out the rows that only have the same IP address.

This query is just a starting point. It could be used as an inline view, or it could enhanced.

Comment: Thank you very much, Now that I can verify the diffrent IPs at the same time I can assure to block them. my last code I could not verify the same time.

Comment: If you want to return the IP addresses, you could add another expression to the SELECT list... **`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.ip ORDER BY t.ip) AS ip_list`**.  Note the length of the string returned by the GROUP_CONCAT function is limited by the setting of `group_concat_max_len` variable. You can change that with a set statement, e.g. `SET group_concat_max_len = 16000`. (To check whether characters may have been chopped off, I check that the length of the returned values is less than `group_concat_max_len`.)